# Custom Prometheus servicemonitor not registering targets

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I've installed Prometheus operator on my kubernetes cluster using the helm chart.  Everything looked to be working pretty well however I have a test app with a /metrics endpoint that I'd like to scrape and I'm not able to get that working.  I've created the servicemonitor for the app and I see in the Prometheus UI that this is getting registered and added to the config however no targets are showing up.

Here is my deployment for the app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: api-bootstrap-grape
  labels:
    name: api-bootstrap-grape
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-tokenreview-binding
  namespace: api-bootstrap-grape
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: vault-auth
  namespace: api-bootstrap-grape
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-bootstrap-grape-service
  namespace: api-bootstrap-grape
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
  ports:
    - name: api-bootstrap-grape-http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-bootstrap-grape-deployment
  namespace: api-bootstrap-grape
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
      annotations:
        # Pull in any secrets from vault and specify the rest of the config here
        # this ends up in /vault/secrets/env
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'api-bootstrap-grape-role'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-env: 'secret/api-bootstrap-grape/config'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-env: |
          {{- with secret "secret/api-bootstrap-grape/config" -}}
          {{- range $k, $v := .Data -}}
          {{ $k }}={{ $v }}
          {{ end -}}
          {{- end -}}
          POSTGRES_HOST=database_host
          POSTGRES_PORT=5432
          POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          USERNAME=appuser
          POSTGRES_DB_PROD=product_production
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: vault-auth
      containers:
      - name: api-bootstrap-grape-app
        image: git.domain.com:4567/dev-toolbox/api-bootstrap-grape:latest
        env:
          - name: RACK_ENV
            value: production
          - name: SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN
            value: api-bootstrap-grape.domain.com
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

The app is working well and I can confirm that I can hit the service for it and /metrics returns correctly.

Here is the servicemonitor that I've added:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: api-bootstrap-grape-servicemonitor
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
    release: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
  endpoints:
  - port: api-bootstrap-grape-http
    path: "/metrics"
    interval: 15s
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - api-bootstrap-grape
```

At this time I think the issue might be that this app is in it's own namespace and prometheus is in the default namespace.  I've tried deploying the service monitor to both the default and the api-bootstrap-grape namespace, neither works.  I'm not sure what else I might be missing.

If the issue is that Prometheus is in the default namespace and it's only monitoring that, how I can I tell it to monitor other namespaces?

edit:  as a test I deployed this app to the default namespace where prometheus lives to see if that was the issue.  I still ran into the same problem, the prometheus config gets updated but no targets get registered so maybe I have another issue with my config above?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I was able to get it working once I added labels to my service. Your service has no labels, but if you add the `selector.matchLabels` that your `ServiceMonitor` is looking for (because it's targeting the `Service`) then it may work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-bootstrap-grape-service
  namespace: api-bootstrap-grape
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
     app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: api-bootstrap-grape-app
  ports:
    - name: api-bootstrap-grape-http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This was my issue. Confusingly, it's **not** targeting the `selectorLabels` for my pods which allow the endpoints to work. It's simply looking at the label on the `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to be able to scrap metrics from a spring boot app.

First ensure that the app emit correctly prometheus metrics, for spring boot add the following to the `application.yaml`:

```
management:
  endpoint.health.probes.enabled: true
  endpoints.web:
    exposure.include: ["prometheus"]
    base-path: /actuator
```

then `curl http:localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus` should print a bunch of logs.

Then on kubernetes templates the `kind: Service` of the app should be like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "my-app"
  namespace: "my-app-namespace"
  labels:
    app: "my-app"
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
...
```

Note the `labels` and the port `name` !

I assume that your prometheus / grafana stack is already setup properly (If you are already able to see the metrics of your cluster components you should be fine).

Then add the `ServiceMonitor` like the following:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: "my-app"
  namespace: "my-app-namespace"
spec:
  endpoints:
    - path: /actuator/prometheus
      port: http
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - "my-app-namespace"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "my-app"
```

Here you can see that:

- The namespace matches the one of your service
- The `path` of the endpoint is the one defined in the `application.yaml` earlier
- The `port` of the endpoint is the `name` of the port defined in the `Service` earlier
- The `selector.matchLabels` uses the labels of the `Service`.

Then restart your prometheus pod (something like `prometheus-grafana-kube-prometheus-st-prometheus` if you use the `kube-prometheus-stack` helm chart), and now you should have your app visible in both the configs and the targets in the prometheus UI !

ref:

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/2451

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#using-textual-port-number-instead-of-port-name